# How do I handle press and unpress touchable component with style changes?

Tags: react-native, reactive-programming, touchableopacity

The idea is to create a specific Touchable component acting like a button and have a feeling of pressed and unpressed, and using this component many times on my app but only one can be pressed at a time. If one is touched and then another one is touched, the first one should be unpressed and the second one should be pressed. The idea is not to use Redux to solve this problem.

I'm already handling which component was pressed, and sending through props the actions to the component. But i don't know how to manage all buttons at the same time in a generic way, by that I mean, not creating a variable to each button.

my App:

```
<View>
<ActivityButton activityTitle={"B1"} submit={() => this.submitHandler("B1")} />
<ActivityButton activityTitle={"B2"} submit={() => this.submitHandler("B2")} />
</View>
```

my Component (ActivityButton):

```
this.state={active:false}

<TouchableOpacity style={this.state.active ? styles.buttonPress : styles.button} onPress={this.props.submit}>
                <View>
                    <Text>{this.props.activityTitle}</Text>
                </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume what you trying to do something like a Radio button groups? If your buttons only located in single page, you can achieve by using state in `MyApp` to check which buttons is enabled instead of button itself.

MyApp

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        buttonIdThatEnable: "",
    };
}

submitHandler = (buttonId) => {
    this.setState({
        buttonIdThatEnable: buttonId,
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <ActivityButton
                activityTitle={"B1"}
                active={this.state.buttonIdThatEnable === "B1"}
                submit={() => this.submitHandler("B1")}
            />
            <ActivityButton
                activityTitle={"B2"}
                active={this.state.buttonIdThatEnable === "B2"}
                submit={() => this.submitHandler("B2")}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
```

ActivityButton (Use props.active to determine style)

```
<TouchableOpacity style={this.props.active ? styles.buttonPress : styles.button} 
    onPress={this.props.submit}>
                <View>
                    <Text>{this.props.activityTitle}</Text>
                </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

If your Buttons are located in different components and you do not want to use Redux, you may consider the [React Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context)

Comment: It worked PERFECTLY as I wanted! Thank you so much!